# R aggregate (key,value) data per row

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, aggregate

I'm trying to create an aggregated list of (key,value) pairs:

```
 d <- data.frame(key.1 = c(1,1),
                 val.1  = c(100,100),
                 key.2 = c(1,1),
                 val.2  = c(100,100),
                 key.3 = c(2,3),
                 val.3 = c(100,100))

key.1 val.1 key.2 val.2 key.3 val.3
    1   100     1   100     2   100
    1   100     1   100     3   100
```

and I want the result to be:

```
key.1 val.1 key.2 val.2
    1   200     2   100
    1   200     3   100
```

Meaning that (1,100) and (1,100) get aggregated based on the common 1, and their value is summed up to 200. the (2,100) on the first row and the (3,100) on the 2nd row remain as they are, since there isn't a common key with another pair.

Unlike     [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6812077/aggregating-values-in-a-data-frame-based-on-key), In my scenario I have to aggregate **each row of my data frame separately**. Currently I'm just iterating row-by-row, and for each row using "aggregate". Is there a smarter way to do it?

Comment: Can you `dput` a sample of your data. This is not a very clearly phrased question.

Comment: @AnandaMahto: added a sample. thx for the suggsetion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution that gets you the values you are looking for, albeit in a slightly different format than the one you have specified in your example output:

1. Create an "ID" based on the `rownames`, since you want to aggregate by row in the end...

   ```
   d$ID <- rownames(d)
   ```
2. Convert your data from "wide" to "long" format using `reshape`

   ```
   temp <- reshape(d, direction = "long", idvar="ID", 
                   varying = setdiff(names(d), "ID"))

   temp
   #     ID time key val
   # 1.1  1    1   1 100
   # 2.1  2    1   1 100
   # 1.2  1    2   1 100
   # 2.2  2    2   1 100
   # 1.3  1    3   2 100
   # 2.3  2    3   3 100
   ```
3. Use `aggregate` to calculate the sum by the combination of rows (ID) and keys (key). Also, create a second "ID" based on the "groups" of the original IDs.

   ```
   temp1 <- aggregate(val ~ ID + key, temp, sum)
   temp1 <- within(temp1, {
     ID2 <- ave(ID, ID, FUN = seq_along)
   })
   temp1
   #   ID key val ID2
   # 1  1   1 200   1
   # 2  2   1 200   1
   # 3  1   2 100   2
   # 4  2   3 100   2
   ```
4. Use `reshape` again to get back to a "wide" form:

   ```
   reshape(temp1, direction = "wide", idvar="ID", timevar="ID2")
   #   ID key.1 val.1 key.2 val.2
   # 1  1     1   200     2   100
   # 2  2     1   200     3   100
   ```

Comment: yes, size should be val. it's a typo. Regarding the rest of your answer - I'm still reading it..

Comment: @zorbar, It's Sunday and I don't have any work to do right now, so I'll be generous and give the full answer.

Answer (score 0):

For this to be possible, the data first needs converting to a "tidy" format. Each key and each val are actually the same variable, and you want to aggregate by key and another variable, column, which isn't explicitly coded. The data should be arranged like this:

```
d <- data.frame(key = c(1,1,1,1,2,3), 
             val = c(100,100,100,100,100,100), 
             keycol = c(1,1,2,2,3,3))
```

Which gives

```
  key val  keycol
#   1 100       1
#   1 100       1
#   1 100       2
#   1 100       2
#   2 100       3
#   3 100       3
```

Now just aggregate by `key` and `keycol` to get the desired result. I like `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% group_by(key, keycol) %>% summarise(sum(val))
```

This gives the result you wanted, in the correct form.

```
     key  keycol sum(val)
   (dbl)   (dbl)    (dbl)
#1     1       1      200
#2     1       2      200
#3     2       3      100
#4     3       3      100
```